# Multi-line parsing

Tags: ruby, regex, parsing, fileparsing

I am parsing a log file:

```
2015-07-15 12:59:39 +0530 [ERROR] index=abc host=abc
2015-07-15 12:59:39 +0530 [WARNING] index=def
host=def
2015-07-15 12:59:39 +0530 [INFO] index=ghi host=ghi
```

Every log starts with a time stamp.

I am thinking to parse the logs individually. I thought of separating them by time stamps and fetching, so I wrote a regex:

```
text = File.open('logs.txt').read
log = text[/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(.*?)^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/m, ].to_s
.gsub(/\s/m,' ').strip.split(' ')
puts log #Prints 2015-07-15 12:59:39 +0530 [ERROR] index=abc host=abc
```

However, this only fetches the first log:

```
2015-07-15 12:59:39 +0530 [ERROR] index=abc host=abc
```

and not the rest.

1. How do I continue getting the logs after the first one?
2. Is there a better way to handle this than my approach?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

1. Use `scan` instead of `[]`.
2. Read line by line instead of reading the entire log file at once.

Comment: 3. `/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(.*?)^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}/m` is too greedy. Should be either positive lookforward, or just `/^\d{4}\-\d{2}\-\d{2}(.*?)$`.

Answer (score 0):

Is your formatting correct, and log can span multiple lines? If they were separated by newlines, you could just use

```
log = text.lines
```

Comment: Hi Borsunho, you are right these are multi-line logs. However, when you tru `text.lines` it will give all the lines. I am looking for the content between two time stamps.